# How can I remove the bottom margin whitespace from colorbox

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I am using colorbox to open a window in the middle of a webpage and I am using the iframe version. At the moment I am just developing the basic code as a model so I can implement it across several applications.

I am trying to clean up the look and simplify it to math my applications and I am stuck with a 28 pixel margin at the bottom of the window. I have been successful in updating the margins by using the technique of hiding the borders and adding a border class like this:

```
$("#cboxContent").addClass("blue_border_example");
```

where blue_border_example is the style I want.

But I am not having any success removing the 28 pixel bottom whitespace. It appears to be coming from the `id="cboxLoadedContent"`, so I have tried adding the statement below in the window code that I am loading:

```
$("#cboxLoadedContent").addClass("remove_bottom_margin");
```

where remove_bottom_margin is the style:

```
.remove_bottom_margin { margin-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

I assumed that this style could be added in the document ready function for the program that is being loaded into the `iframe` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on why this doesn't work and what I should do to solve it?

Comment: Can you include the code snippet in your question or may be a link to codepen

Comment: After 2 days of struggling, I found a simple solution after posting this. I was clearly making this too complicated, assuming that a class had to be added dynamically. I just added the necessary styles (#cboxLoadedContent {margin-bottom: 0px;}
#cboxContent {border: 5px solid #003399; margin: 10px; padding: 10px;} after the colorbox css and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a need to do this via jQuery? Why not do it directly in your css. So there's no need to have those 2 jQuery lines.

Add this in your CSS.

```
#cboxWrapper #cboxLoadedContent,
#cboxWrapper #cboxContent {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what I did. I guess I was seeing this as a more complicated problem than it was.